# How can I make my DIV just the size of the text it encloses

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<div id="one">
<div id="two">my text here</div>
</div>
```

I have styled the div with id=two and put a box around it. The problem is that it doesn't enclose the text but instead expands to the width of the outer DIV. Is there a way I can make it just size to match the text without specifying width?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either

```
#two {
    display: inline; /* or 'inline-block' */
}
```

*Or:*

```
#two {
    float: left; /* or right */
}
```

`display: inline;` stops the `div` being displayed as a block-level element, causing it to collapse (for want of a better word) to the size of its contents. If you use the alternative `display: inline-block` then the `div` retains its ability to have a defined `width` and `height`, which may be required for your layout. However it's worth noting that Internet Explorer 6 and 7 only accepts `display: inline-block` for those elements that are '[naturally inline](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#t03).'

`float` has much the same effect; but using `float` might/will obviously affect the layout of the page, and may need to be cleared by subsequent elements.

Comment: Complete in both available options as well as their limitations. Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

display:inline-block;

This way you keep the block behaviour of your div.